# Filter JSON records to diffrent datasets Spark-Java

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I'm using Java-Spark.

I have the following Java records in rdd from Kafka (As string):

```
{"code":"123", "date":"14/07/2018",....}
{"code":"124", "date":"15/07/2018",....}
{"code":"123", "date":"15/07/2018",....}
{"code":"125", "date":"14/07/2018",....}
```

That I'm read to Dataset as follow:

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession.read().json(jsonSet);
Dataset<Row> dfSelect = df.select(cols);//Where cols is Column[]
```

I want to write the JSON records to different Hive table and different partitions by mapping to diffrent datasets,
Meaning that:

```
{"code":"123", "date":"14/07/2018",....} Write to HDFS dir -> /../table123/partition=14_07_2018
{"code":"124", "date":"15/07/2018",....} Write to HDFS dir -> /../table124/partition=15_07_2018
{"code":"123", "date":"15/07/2018",....} Write to HDFS dir -> /../table123/partition=15_07_2018
{"code":"125", "date":"14/07/2018",....} Write to HDFS dir -> /../table125/partition=14_07_2018
```

How can I mapping the Jsons by code and by date and then write by:

```
dfSelectByTableAndDate123.write().format("parquet").mode("append").save(pathByTableAndDate);
dfSelectByTableAndDate124.write().format("parquet").mode("append").save(pathByTableAndDate);
dfSelectByTableAndDate125.write().format("parquet").mode("append").save(pathByTableAndDate);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can convert you json to java objects, then reduce it by date which will give you rows grouped by same date. Each set then you can write as you wish below is pseudo code in scala

```
case class MyType(code: String,date: String)

newDs = df.as[MyType]

newDs.reduceByKey("date").values
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If my json contains dynamic fields, how can I serialize only those fields and not all JSON string to MyType object?

Comment: You can include only required fields in MyType. You don't need to include all fields

Comment: Ok, There is something like reduceByKey in Java-Spark?